# Setting iOS UIImagePickerController to Landscape mode for external display

Tags: ios, swift, camera, orientation, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm creating an app for an art installation which will mimic Apple's own camera app, but with slight modifications (slight video display parameters, front camera only, etc.). Everything is working for the most part, however I will have the camera connected to an external monitor, and therefore need it to display in landscape mode, not portrait mode. I have it connected via Lightning to HDMI.

I am using UIImagePickerController and not AVFoundation, because by default it does face detection which is identical to Apple's own (the yellow squares around the faces). I get the feeling that replicating the face detection in AV foundation would be a significant amount of trouble. However, UIImagePickerController simply refuses to display in landscape mode. This is the message in the reference about it:

> The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the camera interface and your code.

from: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller

Is what I want to do still possible? I am already using a cameraOverlayView, however that so far has not fixed the problem? Can I just change things for HDMI display? Since I will not be submitting this app to apple, I don't particularly need to follow their standards as long as I can install it on my own iPhone 7 Plus running 10.1.1.

Here is my current code in case it helps:

```
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200))
        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.5, green: 1.0, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1)
        myView.alpha = 0.1
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType =
            UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera

        imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.front
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityType.type640x480
        //imagePicker.showsCameraControls = false
        imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = myView
        imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.currentContext

        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true,
                     completion: nil)
```

Comment: For iPhones, UIImagePicker only displays in portrait. But for iPads, it orients in both portrait and landscape. Maybe if you could convince the external screen (or more likely, your code) that you have an iPad.... It's a long shot.

Comment: Any idea how I could do that? Apple seems pretty clear on which device it is...

Comment: Well, maybe - and it's a ton of work. Subclass UIImagePickerController. It's possible (I just tried) and it's a subclass of UINavigationController(!) and NSCoding. Since UINavigationController is a subclass of UIViewController you have an override for `supportedInterfaceOrientations`. What I couldn't find was *how* UIImagePickerController doesn't support portrait for iPhones (I can guess why). Maybe it'll work. Or maybe the least path of resistance is to use a third party image picker that does what you want.